# AngularJS $scope data is not showing any thing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

The `submitform()` does not take the for datas to the function. Chrome console says **ReferenceError: $ is not defined**. Is there anything wrong in the code ?
[image]

```js
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('testimonialController', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.formdata = {};
      $scope.submission = false;
      $scope.submitform = function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'sendmail.php',
          data: $.param($scope.formdata), // pass in data as strings
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).
        success(function() {
          console.log("send successfuly");
        }).
        error(function() {
          console.log("It is failed");
        });
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="contact-form" ng-controller="testimonialController" ng-app="app">
  <h1 id="contact">Contact</h1>
  <pre>Form data: {{formdata}}</pre>
  <p>Take a look around the site, Do you have something in mind you would like to let me know .You can contact me by filling the form below or email hello@athimannil.com</p>
  <form ng-submit="submitform()">
    <div class="form-wrap">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formdata.name" placeholder="Name" required>
      <br>

    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="formdata.email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <br>

    </div>
    <div class="form-wrap">
      <label for="comment">Message</label>
      <br>
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment" ng-model="formdata.comment" placeholder="Comment" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
      <br>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the **console** message when use
[image]

```
$http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : 'sendmail.php',
    data    : $scope.formdata,  // pass in data as strings
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
}).
```

Comment: Why do you use `data : $.param($scope.formdata)` and not just `$scope.formdata` ?

Comment: @Jeyp I just followed this tutorial http://webdevmatters.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/processing-a-form-with-angularjs-php/

Comment: @Jeyp Console error is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'formdata' of undefined** when remove $.param as `data    : $scope.formdata`

Comment: The issue really is, that you dont include jQuery. However, is there a special reason why you  use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as *Content-Type*? If not, just go with `application/json` and then it will be enough to just pass `$scope.formdata` as you did in your second approach.

Answer (score 1):

`data: $.param($scope.formdata)`

This line uses jQuery's `$.param` method. You have to include it, if you want to use it

Comment: I am not using jQuery in the function

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil - Yes you are. I'm citing the article that you linked: `Ok, I’ll be honest, there’s a quick cheat here. I’m using jQuery’s $.param to help me send data`.

Comment: Any solution without using jQuery ?

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Yeah, you should read my comment on your original post.